# LTSpice - resistor controlled by RMS

Tags: ltspice, education

Is possible to obtain a resistor controlled by RMS of a voltage in LTSpice? The syntax \$R=V(n001)\$ works, whereas \$R=rms(V(n001))\$ does not work.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, rms doesn't exist at a specific point in time but over an interval, and those are hard to get, the best you could maybe get is an integration via idt() to hack something together that is close

Comment: LTspice certainly can't do that as simply as that. The RMS obtained over which period of time, anyway? Maybe the easiest is to assign a node with the square value of your input, apply a low-pass filter on it, and then apply sqrt on that. Then assign your R value from this.

Answer (score 4):

RMS is a computed value related to the "output" and therefore it cannot be used to change the value of a component (an input value) because you get a circular problem. Maybe you can take Vn001, and feed it through an RMS to DC converter. Maybe use a multiplier to get v\$^2\$ then low pass filter it then, use a square root circuit: -

[image]

Most sims have the multiplier "part" and, with an ideal op-amp (not a TL081 as shown above) you can extract the square root and hence the RMS.

Comment: Hi @Andy aka, I tried to realize your circuit with LTSpice. The only block which I know is the ideal op-amp. Could you help me to insert MUL and SQRT please?

Comment: SQRT is the output just as IN is the input. MUL should be available in LTSPICE - it is a numerical multiplier of two values. I mentioned in my answer that you should use a multiplier to get \$v^2\$ - it's identical.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linear's brilliantly simple method, see [this](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn288f.pdf), for example. At its simplest, you have something like this:

[image: rms]

The readings are a bit off due to the lack of an imposed timestep and no `.opt plotwinsize=0`, it's just a quicly made schematic. The output filter is a 2nd order Bessel, for less overshoot -- which you still have due to the feedback-mode of the circuit. Add your own filter, here's for example, a 2nd order Cauer with 0.01dB ripple, 80dB stopband, frequency scaling at 3dB:

[image: Cauer]

This is only the RMS part, in rest, it's up to you, though it looks like a behavioural resistor is more appropiate.